# Qml QTouchDevice

Tags: qt, qml, touchscreen

I am new in Qt. I am working on windows desktop application and using Qt with qml. On PC that hasn't `QTouchDevices`, splitter between component (element that allow you resize component on window) works good with mouse (screenshot "Good distance"), but if screen is touchscreen I have next problem, please look on screenshot "Wrong distance".

My application shouldn't support any touch device. So how to disable this Qt feature? I need the same behavior like on device without touch screen.

**Wrong distance**

[image: Wrong distance]

**Good distance**

[image: Good distance]

I have tried disable touch device using privet methods using next sample:

```
QWindowSystemInterface::unregisterTouchDevice(QTouchDevice::devices().first());
```

This works, but `QWindowSystemInterface` is private class and it disable touchscreen. And one more in `QTCreator` splitters work fine, exactly as I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't patch Qt, the only way that I can think of would be to iterate through the children, searching for the `MouseArea`. For example, suppose you had this QML:

```
import QtQuick 2.5
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.1

ApplicationWindow {
    width: 600
    height: 400
    visible: true

    property alias splitView: splitView

    SplitView {
        id: splitView
        anchors.fill: parent

        Rectangle {
            width: 200
            Layout.maximumWidth: 400
            color: "lightblue"
            Text {
                text: "View 1"
                anchors.centerIn: parent
            }
        }

        Rectangle {
            id: centerItem
            Layout.minimumWidth: 50
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            color: "lightgray"
            Text {
                text: "View 2"
                anchors.centerIn: parent
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You could then print out the object tree of the `SplitView` like so:

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QQuickItem>
#include <QDebug>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));

    QObject *window = engine.rootObjects().first();
    QQuickItem *splitView = window->property("splitView").value<QQuickItem*>();
    splitView->dumpObjectTree();

    return app.exec();
}
```

That gives you:

```
SplitView_QMLTYPE_1:: 
    QQmlComponent:: 
    QQuickSystemPalette:: 
    QObject_QML_2:: 
    QQmlComponent:: 
    QQuickItem:: 
    QQuickItem:: 
    QQuickItem:: 
        QQuickLoader_QML_3:: 
            QObject_QML_4:: 
            QQuickMouseArea_QML_5:: 
            QQuickRectangle:: 
                QQmlContext:: 
    QQuickItem:: 
    QQmlComponentAttached:: 
    QQuickRectangle:: 
        QQuickText:: 
        QQuickLayoutAttached:: 
    QQuickRectangle:: 
        QQuickText:: 
        QQuickLayoutAttached:: 
    QQuickLayoutAttached::
```

`QObject::dumpObjectTree()` [prints out `metaObject->className()`](http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/src/corelib/kernel/qobject.cpp#n3957), so we know to look for an object whose `metaObject` has a `className` matching that:

Then:

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QQuickItem>
#include <QScreen>
#include <QWindow>
#include <QDebug>

QQuickItem *findMouseArea(QQuickItem *item)
{
    foreach (QQuickItem *childItem, item->childItems()) {
        if (QString(childItem->metaObject()->className()).startsWith(QStringLiteral("QQuickMouseArea_QML"))) {
            return childItem;
        } else {
            QQuickItem *mouseArea = findMouseArea(childItem);
            if (mouseArea) {
                return mouseArea;
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));

    QWindow *window = qobject_cast<QWindow*>(engine.rootObjects().first());
    QQuickItem *splitView = window->property("splitView").value<QQuickItem*>();
    QQuickItem *mouseArea = findMouseArea(splitView);
    mouseArea->setProperty("defaultMargin", QVariant(window->screen()->physicalDotsPerInch() / 25.4));

    return app.exec();
}
```

Apparently, `Screen::pixelDensity` [is calculated](http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtdeclarative.git/tree/src/quick/items/qquickscreen.cpp#n270) using the physical dots per inch of the screen, divided by `25.4`, so we copy that as well. You could use any other value there.

You will need to adapt the code should a second `MouseArea` ever be introduced, for example.

It's still largely dependent on private API, but it doesn't touch Qt code, at least.

Answer (score 0):

## Quick&Easy: enable/disable mouse and touch synthesizing

No need to patch things or doing any crazy tree lookups, [just enable or disable mouse or touch synthesizing](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#ApplicationAttribute-enum).

- Qt::AA_SynthesizeTouchForUnhandledMouseEvents
- Qt::AA_SynthesizeMouseForUnhandledTouchEvents

[Just disable what you don't want](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtouchevent.html#mouse-events-and-touch-event-synthesizing), either mouse or touch to accept only authentic events.